# How to reset scroll value on scroll down on Button click and manual?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I am implementing a web page in which I want to scroll down to the next element on click on an item. This is working fine when it has specific sequence but if I am to change an item in particular section after selecting wrong item this sequence gets messed up. Code snippet is given below.

```js
$('.item').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).parent().parent().find('p')
    .removeClass('selectedItem');
  $(this).find('p')
    .addClass('selectedItem');
  e.preventDefault();
  var $current = $('.first'),
    $next = $current.nextAll('.step').first();
  if (!$next.length) {
    $next = $('.step').first();
  }

  if ($next.length) {


    var $next = $next.first();
    var top = $next.offset().top;

    $current.removeClass('first');

    $('body').stop(true, true).delay(1000).animate({
      scrollTop: top
    }, 1000, function() {

      $next.addClass('first');

    });
  }
});
```

```css
.selectedItem {
  background-color: red;
}

.step {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 500px;
}

.item {
  border: 2px white solid;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
}

p {
  margin: 5px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="step first">
  <h1 class='section'>
First Section
</h1>
  <div class="item">
    <p>
      hello
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>
      hello
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>
      hello
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>
      hello
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>
      hello
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="step">
  <h1 class='section'>
Second Section
</h1>
  <div class="item">
    <p>
      hello
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>
      hello
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>
      hello
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>
      hello
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>
      hello
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="step">
  <h1 class='section'>
Third Section
</h1>
  <div class="item">
    <p>
      hello
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>
      hello
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>
      hello
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>
      hello
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>
      hello
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

In above given example there are three section and lets say if I click on an item in section 1 then scroll goes down to the section 2. Same applies on section 2's item but if I manually scroll up to the previous section and re correct my item this sequence gets messed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that you were finding the next target by the added class, and not by the clicked element. this works

```js
$('.item').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).parent().parent().find('p')
    .removeClass('selectedItem');
  $(this).find('p')
    .addClass('selectedItem');
  e.preventDefault();
  var $current = $(this).closest(".step");
  var $next = $current.next('.step');
  console.log($next);
  if (!$next.length) {
    $next = $('.step').first();
  }

  var top = $next.offset().top;

  $('body').stop(true, true).delay(1000).animate({
    scrollTop: top
  }, 1000);

});
```

```css
.selectedItem {
  background-color: red;
}
.step {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 500px;
}
.item {
  border: 2px white solid;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
}
p {
  margin: 5px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="step first">
  <h1 class='section'>
First Section
</h1>
  <div class="item">
    <p>
      hello
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>
      hello
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>
      hello
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>
      hello
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>
      hello
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="step">
  <h1 class='section'>
Second Section
</h1>
  <div class="item">
    <p>
      hello
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>
      hello
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>
      hello
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>
      hello
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>
      hello
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="step">
  <h1 class='section'>
Third Section
</h1>
  <div class="item">
    <p>
      hello
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>
      hello
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>
      hello
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>
      hello
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>
      hello
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```